# JavaScript stops other Scripts on the Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, controls

Well....!!!

I have Two Scripts on the Page for Two Purposes

1)  For DropDown  List

2) For POPUP Messages

They work without any problems independently, but one script blocks the rest from running properly wherever I include it.

Add New

Modify

Delete

and When I click Modify Or Delete  To Execute The POP Message , The POP message Will Execute successfuly and when cancel or save Changes what ever I want On POP Message after when I return To the Page The Dropdown List Stop Functioning , its Not Drop the List above.

For Drop Down List I Used This JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $('.dropdown1').mouseenter(function () {
        $('.sublinks1').stop(false, true).hide();
        var submenu = $(this).parent().next();
        submenu.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 'px',
            left: $(this).offset().left + 'px',
            zIndex: 1000
        });
        submenu.stop().slideDown(300);
        submenu.mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).slideUp(300);
        });
    });
});
```

While For POP Message I used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function ClearFields() {

      };

      function CloseModal(msg) {
          $('#myModal').modal('hide');
          if (msg.length > 0) {
              alert(msg);
          }
      }

      function ShowModal() {
          $('#myModal').modal('show');
      }
</script>
```

Referenced On The Page

```
<link href="../StyleSheet/DropDownMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../JsQuery/1.10.2jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../JsQuery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../JsQuery/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For Message Box

```
<link href="../MessageBox/BootStrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Also Also
Also

Note: Actually The Entire Codes Or HTML used in ascx

Comment: Why have you multiple jquery files just use one. Multiple files will conflict with each other and stop scripts from being executed.

Comment: So Which One .... The Higher Version ...? Give me an Example Please

Comment: Yes i would recommend the latest version.

Comment: So which one should I used among These above and What is the diference Between .js and .min.js

Comment: ok use JsQuery/1.10.2jquery.min.js. Difference is that min.js is minified or compressed version which is smaller in size and used for production enviornment and .js is larger in size used for development enviornment,

Comment: Well Mairaj Ahmad Thank You So much For Helping me.... I used JsQuery/1.10.2jquery.min.js  But still The Problem remain same...

Comment: OK see browser console to check if you see any error there ?